# Listview scrolled back shows wrong imageview

Tags: android, android-listview, android-imageview, android-view

I want to create a listview where each element has several imageview, but they will never be shown together; they will be shown according to the data they want to describe.
This is a part of the element layout

```
<ImageView
    style="@style/release_item_resolution_pic"
    android:id="@+id/release_res_standard"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/release_label_title"
    android:src="@drawable/format_standard" />

<ImageView
    style="@style/release_item_resolution_pic"
    android:id="@+id/release_res_720p"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/release_res_standard"
    android:src="@drawable/format_720p" />

<ImageView
    style="@style/release_item_resolution_pic"
    android:id="@+id/release_res_webdl"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/release_res_720p"
    android:src="@drawable/format_webdl" />

<ImageView
    style="@style/release_item_resolution_pic"
    android:id="@+id/release_res_dvdrip"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/release_res_webdl"
    android:src="@drawable/format_dvdrip" />
```

Keep in mind that every element has its visibility set to "gone".
To set which picture show I use this loop, into the getView() method:

```
            for(VideoFormat format:selectedRel.getResolutions()){
            ImageView resolutionPic=getResolutionImageView(format, contentView);
            resolutionPic.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
```

and it works fine, except when I scroll the list and then get back to the first elements. It looks like the list loads other pictures, even if it's not supposed to; after some times the uncesessary pictures disappear, but it takes too much time. What can I do to avoid all this, and always get the right picture visible?
EDIT:
This is the getResolutionImageView method:

```
private ImageView getResolutionImageView(VideoFormat format, View contentView){
        switch(format){
        case BDRIP:
            return (ImageView)contentView.findViewById(R.id.release_res_bdrip);

        case BLURAY:
            return (ImageView)contentView.findViewById(R.id.release_res_bd);

        case DVDRIP:
            return (ImageView)contentView.findViewById(R.id.release_res_dvdrip);

        case HD_1080i:
            return (ImageView)contentView.findViewById(R.id.release_res_1080i);

        case HD_1080p:
            return (ImageView)contentView.findViewById(R.id.release_res_1080p);

        case HD_720p:
            return (ImageView)contentView.findViewById(R.id.release_res_720p);

        default:
            return (ImageView)contentView.findViewById(R.id.release_res_standard);

        case WEB_DL:
            return (ImageView)contentView.findViewById(R.id.release_res_webdl);

        }
    }
```

Comment: post `getResolutionImageView` method..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When list view scrolls it's `getView` method called. But the `convertView` which it gets may contains old data. (data of other list rows).

So here is the solution

in `getView` method when you set the `Visibility` of one image, set `Invisible` of all other ImageViews.